# How to keep an App Engine/Java app running with deaf requests from a Java/Python web cron?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest, keep-alive

1. App Engine allows you 30 seconds to load your application
2. My application takes around 30 seconds - sometimes more, sometimes less. I don't know how to fix this.
3. If the app is idle (does not receive a request for a while), it needs to be re-loaded.

So, to avoid the app needing to be reloaded, I want to simulate user activity by pinging the app every so often.

But there's a catch . . .

If I ping the app and it has already been unloaded by App Engine, my web request will be the first request to the app and the app will try to reload. This could take longer than 30 seconds and exceed the loading time limit.

So my idea is to ping the app but not wait for the response. I have simulated this manually by going to the site from a browser, making the request and immediately closing the browser - it seems to keep the app alive.

Any suggestions for a good way to do this in a Python or Java web cron (I'm assuming a Python solution will be simpler)?

Comment: why your app gets 30 seconds to load? what are you using? log4j?

Comment: I think dfa has the right idea - it is probably a better use of your time to figure out why it takes 30 seconds for your app to load.  How long does a typical request take once it is loaded?  Does it take 30 seconds to start up when you run it in the dev environment or only when deployed?  Are you factoring large numbers in a static initializer somewhere? :)

Comment: Definitely better to figure out why your app takes 30 seconds to start up. That's an extremely long time for a webapp.

Comment: Hi, lets assume he will reduce it to 5s, is this reasonable to have 5s overhead on each request - NO! 
Creating cron or any other kind of periodic HTTP requests to keep instance up and running make no sense. First - there is no evidence that this instance will serve next coming request (eg. from different network location etc.), second - it will consume Quota
(which is less a problem). 
I consider this as a blocker for GAE production use...

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier use the [cron built in to App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html) to keep your application alive.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is just:

```
import httplib
hcon = httplib.HTTPConnection("foo.appspot.com")
hcon.request("GET", "/someURL")
hcon.close()
```

Comment: httplib on App Engine is implemented in terms of the urlfetch API - this snippet won't do what you expect.

Comment: Nick, it was my understanding he was planning to run this ping code on a computer /outside/ App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest Java http pinger:

```
URLConnection hcon = new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
hcon.connect();
hcon.getInputStream().read();
```

Answer (score 1):

App engine also has a new PAY feature where you can have it "always-on".  Costs about $0.30 USD cents a day.  Just go into your billing settings and enable it if you don't mind paying for the feature.  I believe it guarantees you at least 3 instances always running.

(I didn't realize hitting a /ping url which caused an instance to spin up would cause it to exceed the 30 sec limit!)